# How can I concatenate a label not in a macro definition? (in GAS assembler)

Tags: assembly, macros, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I want to do this:

```
i=0
.rept 3
    add rcx,[a?(i*2+1)]
    i=i+1
.endr
```

It should output this:

```
add rcx,[a1]
add rcx,[a3]
add rcx,[a5]
```

I can't find any solution to this problem. I don't want it to be inside a macro definition.

Comment: Are you building your asm with gcc?  If so, you can also use the C preprocessor with a CPP macro to paste two args together.  Except that doesn't work if it happens before `gas` sees the `.rept`.  Hmm.

Comment: I don't believe its possible to do without using macros.

Comment: I'd be curious why you can't use macros?

Comment: @MichaelPetch It's hard to say definitively given how much a big pile of poo binutils is, but I don't think you can do the string manipulation you need here without using macros.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I edited my question. I don't think you could do that with macros. *Please prove me wrong :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe you can solve this without using macros or some other type of pre-processing. The GNU assembler method of doing this could look something like:

```
.altmacro

.macro addmac val
    add rcx, [a\val]
.endm

.macro loopmac
    i=0
    .rept 3
        addmac %(i*2+1)
        i=i+1
    .endr
.endm
```

You then use the `loopmac` macro like this:

```
loopmac
```

You'll need the [.altmacro](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Altmacro.html) directive to be able to process `%(i*2+1)` properly:

> 7.4 .altmacro
>
> You can write ‘%expr’ to evaluate the expression expr and use the result as a string.

Rather than using [`.rept`](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/as_7.html#SEC110) you could use [`.irp`](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/as_7.html#SEC95) and simplify the macro to:

```
.macro loopmac
    .irp i,1,3,5
        add rcx, [a\i]
    .endr
.endm
```

The last example doesn't need `.altmacro` processing.